# Removing a Tag from a webpage on android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to remove the "header" element from a webpage with the help of this answer [Display a part of the webpage on the webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257929/display-a-part-of-the-webpage-on-the-webview-android)

But I am getting an error message; see this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15065300/Check-2.jpg

Here is my full code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('myDiv1')[0].style.display="none"; " +
                    "})()");
        }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://skyasim.info/abc.html");

    }

}
```

Manifest permission as well

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape your `"`.  See the [Escape Sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) section.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
    "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " +
    "})()");
```

Comment: Thank you @james It removes the warning but the code doesn't work!

Comment: I have found this code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257929/display-a-part-of-the-webpage-on-the-webview-android

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:var con = document.getElementById('a'); " +
                "con.parentNode.removeChild(con); ");
```

htmlCode:

```
    <ul>
............
     <div id="a">               
                <H4 align="center"> something</H4>  
     </div>                 
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="row"></div>
```

```java
webview.loadUrl("javascript:if (typeof(document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0]) != 'undefined' && document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0] != null){document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].style.display = 'none';} void 0");
```

Comment: you can add in  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
                view.loadUrl("javascript:var footer = document.getElementById('footer'); footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer); var header = document.getElementById('header-full'); header.parentNode.removeChild(header);");

            }

Comment: You can [edit] your answer, don't post code in comments.

Comment: Ok you can add in onPageFinished Method like view.loadUrl("javascript:var footer = document.getElementById('footer');