# Android WebView loading part of a website

Tags: android, android-webview

Some websites have comments portion and many other unnecessary portions. I want to just display the main article excluding the other portions in my custom Android `WebView`.

I have tried the example from [Display a part of the webpage on the webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257929/display-a-part-of-the-webpage-on-the-webview-android)

But it still shows the full website.

There is also the `loaddatawithbaseurl` class in Android but it is not working too as you can't specify till which portion of a website to show using this class.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here it is with some changes...

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
  {
    String javaScript = "javascript: var form = document.getElementsByClassName('university_corner');"
                        + "var body = document.getElementsByTagName('div');"
                        + "body[0].innerHTML = form[0].innerHTML";
    webView.loadUrl(javaScript);
  }
});
webView.loadUrl(url);
```