# How to display some part of webpage in android webview?

Tags: android

I am using an android `WebView` and I want to load webpage on my android device but display only some parts of webpage, not the whole page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you showing your website URL or someone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is remove some content from your HTML page and then display it in the WebView. This is possible via javascript so just before you display the page add some javascript code that will remove the elements you don't want.

**LIKE**

```
final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebViewId);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
 @Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
        "document.getElementById('tableid')[0].style.display='none'; " +
        "})()");
}
});
mWebView.loadUrl(youUrl);
```

Just replace `document.getElementsByTagName('tableid')` with `document.getElementsByTagName('theElementYouWantToRemove')` for every element and you're set. Original solution can be found at [Display a part of the webpage on the webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257929/display-a-part-of-the-webpage-on-the-webview-android)

Comment: What about the only show the selected part. Without removing the unwanted part, selecting the wanted one. For example, if someone add new div to web page, you must change the client code.

Answer (score 1):

for those who still looking for a solution:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
      {
          mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                 "document.getElementsByClassName('className1')[0].remove();
                  document.getElementsByClassName('className2')[0].remove();
                  document.getElementsByClassName('className3')[0].remove();" +
                        "})()");
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin in this way:

```
view.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                view.loadUrl(
                    "javascript:(function() { " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display='true'; " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('art-bnr')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('container-box')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-sidebar')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                            "})()"
                )                    }            }
        view.loadUrl(url)
```