# How to display a part of the webpage on the webview android

Tags: java, android, webview, jsoup

I am trying to extract small portion from webpage and load into webview
 I have tried following solution given in the link,But it did not work

[Display a part of the webpage on the webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257929/display-a-part-of-the-webpage-on-the-webview-android/40477051#40477051)

**Extracting data using getElementsByClass("darewod")**

```
htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect(htmlPageUrl).get();
element = htmlDocument.getElementsByClass("darewod");  

String html = element.toString();
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
```

I have tried the following two methods to load to webview but it seems not working,Its just printing HTML on UI

```
  wv1.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

  wv1.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
```

Can you please tell me if i am missing anything here?

Comment: Can you either share the url or the content of `String html`? Problem might be: `html` isn't a valid html document anymore and is missing all head definitions (CSS, etc.).

Comment: Html has this value                                                                             <div class="darewod">
 <a title="Workout of the Day" href="/workouts/lower-abs-workout.html" rel="alternate"><img src="/images/grid/wod/2016/wod_nov8.jpg" alt="Workout of the Day"></a>
</div>                                                                                                             Is this valid html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are loading your html code without the proper [structure](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp) (so all definitions in `head` are lost, like CSS references) and without the initial document (or loading with base url) all relative paths are broken.

```
<div class="darewod"> <a title="Workout of the Day" href="/workouts/lower-abs-workout.html" rel="alternate"><img src="/images/grid/wod/2016/wod_nov8.jpg" alt="Workout of the Day"></a> </div>
```

What you could do: replace the body of your document with your selected element, therby preserving the structure and information regarding base:

**Example Code**

```
WebView wv;
Handler uiHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    new BackgroundWorker().execute();

}

// load links in WebView instead of default browser
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @RequiresApi(21)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return false;
    }
}

private class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        getDarewod();
        return null;
    }

    public void getDarewod(){

        try {
            Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect("http://darebee.com/").get();
            Element element = htmlDocument.select("#gkHeaderMod > div.darewod").first();

            // replace body with selected element
            htmlDocument.body().empty().append(element.toString());
            final String html = htmlDocument.toString();

            uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @suv It would probably be better to open a new question.

Comment: Well I have already solved it and in my case there is no need of  this structure. What i was missing is setting javascript enabled to true.