# How to show multiple html files using same layout?

Tags: android, webview

I am developing android quiz app. I created questions as html files and copied in asset folder. I need to show these html files, one by one in Webview while swiping left to right.

Comment: Please show your code. You can create buttons on each page and communicate with Java code — and in Java code you can reload webview's page.

Comment: But why you don't use cordova/react native/etc if you want to use html/js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tabbed activity with only a viewpager. and add webviews as fragments. And load each HTML page to the fragment. See [Tabbed Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral#java)

Comment: Somehow i completed the webview with multiple html loading. I have one more doubt. It is possible to show some portion of html file instead of showing full content.

Comment: Refer this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257929/display-a-part-of-the-webpage-on-the-webview-android)