# How to display a part of the webpage using WebViewController plugin in Flutter?

Tags: webview, flutter

I have a **div id** as campaign-nav and **class id** as campaign-term-list and also

I don’t want to show a header, menu, and footer. In Android, I can do with below code: (WebViewController android code found: [Display a part of the webpage on the webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257929/display-a-part-of-the-webpage-on-the-webview-android))

**How can I display a part of the webpage using WebViewController plugin in Flutter?**

```
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String URL)
            {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-sidebar')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "})()");

            }
        });
        view.loadUrl("your url");
```

**UPDATE:**
Flutter example has;

```
 final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
```

And they use _controller as;

```
new WebView(
              initialUrl:
                  'h****s://mysite.com/campaing/',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
                _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
              ].toSet(),

              onPageFinished: (String url) {
                print('Page finished loading: $url');

                //Here is I put a boolean variable so I can show a progress indicator
                setState(() {
                  _loadedPage = true;

                });
              },
            ),
```

**Update-2:**
In my web page I have footer as shown below.

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="footer-menu">
```

I put your code inside below _controller.complete(webViewController); part. But still shows the footer.

```
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
                webViewController.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-menu')[0].style.display='none';");
              },
```

When I try to put webViewController.evaluateJavascript inside onPageFinished part it doesn't find the ".evaluateJavascript" part.

**Update-3:**
**Full code:(not working)**

```
new WebView(
              initialUrl: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller){
                _myController = controller;
              },
              javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
                _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
              ].toSet(),
              onPageFinished: (url){
                print('Page finished loading: $url');
                _myController.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display='none';");
                setState(() {
                  _loadedPage = true;
                });
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done it myself so far but as stated in the official API from the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package, you should be able to achieve this by calling the `evaluateJavascript` method provided by the `WebViewController` as seen [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController/evaluateJavascript.html).

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
    // here you can access the WebViewController
    controller.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display='none';");
  },
  ...
```

I used the example `JavaScript` code from your snippet as a reference. As stated in the API you might need to wait until the `WebView` has run all `JavaScript` code from the website before you run your own to make sure everything is loaded and the element you try to find is present. To do so there is a `onPageFinished` callback provided by the `WebView`:

```
...
WebViewController _controller;
...

WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
    _controller = controller;
  },
  onPageFinished: (url) {
    _controller.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display='none';");
  },
  ...
```

Comment: the plugin example use _controller as shown in my updated question. I can't find _controller.evaluateJavascript? Any idea why?

Comment: I use your code and update my question. It doesn't find the .evaluateJavascript part.

Comment: Also I have this in AppBar copying from plugin example code.  actions: <Widget>[
          NavigationControls(_controller.future),
        ],

Answer (score 1):

```
I loaded google website and customizing the UI and it was working, but when i want to customize microsoft power apps in my webview of mobile it was not working, but when i tested in my mac chrome browser, i am able to customize in console by typing the javascript style commands. 

The below code is working for customizing the mobile webView    

return WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://www.google.com/",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
            _myController = webViewController;


          // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
          javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
            _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
          ].toSet(),
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            print('allowing navigation to $request');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            print('Page finished loading: $url');

_myController.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"zGVn2e\")[0].style.display='none';");
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Read below article for complete tutorial:
https://medium.com/@yugandhar0189/flutter-ios-android-customize-the-ui-inside-the-webview-e72fbe51dd44

Answer (score -2):

Flutter plugin that provides a WebView widget.

On iOS the WebView widget is backed by a WKWebView; On Android the WebView widget is backed by a WebView.

Use this lib
[here you can use this lib](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

Comment: that plugin I am using

Comment: I update my code (Update-3:) do you know how to make it work the _myController.evaluateJavascript part?